# Call BLAS ddot routine from SBCL

Tags: common-lisp, blas, sbcl, dot-product

I am trying to call the BLAS ddot routine from SBCL.

Based on:

- the ddot documentation (http://www.netlib.org/lapack/explore-html/d5/df6/ddot_8f.html),
- its source code (http://www.netlib.org/lapack/explore-html/d5/df6/ddot_8f_source.html),
- some additional hint (https://orion.math.iastate.edu/docs/cmlib/blas/ddot),
- a working example of calling the dgemm routine ([Matrix-multiplication using BLAS from Common Lisp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29822509/matrix-multiplication-using-blas-from-common-lisp/31068533#31068533))

I came up with the following script:

```
(load-shared-object "libblas.so.3")

(declaim (inline ddot))

(define-alien-routine ("ddot_" ddot) void
  (n int :copy)
  (dx (* double))
  (incx int :copy)
  (dy (* double))
  (incy int :copy))

(defun pointer (array)
  (sap-alien (sb-sys:vector-sap (array-storage-vector array)) (* double)))

(defun dot (dx dy)
  (unless (= (length dx) (length dy))
    (error "Vectors length does not match"))
  (let ((n (length dx))
    (result 0.0d0))
    (sb-sys:with-pinned-objects (dx dy result)
      (ddot n (pointer dx) 1 (pointer dy) 1))))
```

However, the following script:

```
(defvar *a* (make-array 4 :initial-element 1.0d0 :element-type 'double-float))
(defvar *b* (make-array 4 :initial-element 2.0d0 :element-type 'double-float))
(dot *a* *b*)
```

produces the following error:

```
arithmetic error FLOATING-POINT-INVALID-OPERATION signalled
   [Condition of type FLOATING-POINT-INVALID-OPERATION]
```

Any hint?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found it. Credits to Miroslav Urbanek from Charles University in Prague for the hint.

```
-(define-alien-routine ("ddot_" ddot) void
+(define-alien-routine ("ddot_" ddot) double

 (defun dot (dx dy)
   (unless (= (length dx) (length dy))
     (error "Vectors length does not match"))
-  (let ((n (length dx))
-        (result 0.0d0))
-    (sb-sys:with-pinned-objects (dx dy result)
+  (let ((n (length dx)))
+    (sb-sys:with-pinned-objects (dx dy)
```

The ddot routine is meant to return a double, not a void. And the result variable is useless. Things are so obvious *after* you realize them :-)

Answer (score 3):

I know it doesn't directly answer your question but have you tried using an already written binding to Blas? For exampme [Matlisp](https://github.com/matlisp/matlisp) already provides an lispy interface to [dot](https://github.com/matlisp/matlisp/blob/t2/src/blas/dot.lisp#L77)